# Pascal Exception

Tags: delphi, pascal

Isn't it legal to write an expression like this in Pascal:

```
b += c;  {Take whatever in b and add what in c to it, then assign it back to b}
```

or do you have to write

```
b := b + c;
```

I was wondering if the top way was legal in Pascal, Object or Delphi, or if you had to do it old school such as on the bottom.

Comment: You can do this in C/C++, but not in pascal.

Comment: What happens when you try it? What does the compiler tell you? It seems to me you could have figured this out yourself faster than you could click `Ask Question` and write the first sentence here. We're very glad to help, but you should learn now to not be totally helpless without us.

Comment: Last time I wrote `b += c;` in a delphi program, the compiler told me it wasn't valid...  But maybe it doesn't know proper Pascal syntax.

Comment: Why do you think that's proper Pascal syntax?

Comment: @MBo - they do: uniform interface for adding items to collections (lists, arrays, sets) for example. Of course at the price of potential confusion.

same thing with ':=' not generating any value while in C-based languages you can `a =b =c =d`. So basically Pascal enforces verbosity, eine action - eine statement. And sacrifices concise laconic shorthands. That is the reason lambda's in Delphi are so obese with boilerplate to be hardly practical

Comment: @KenBourassa well, strictly speaking Delphi is no more Pascal but a Pascal-based derivative :-D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the Delphi documentation describes the proper syntax

Answer (score 6):

You have to do it the old way using

```
b := b + c;
```

This always works both for plain variables and for properties.

Or use:

```
Inc(b,c);
```

However `Inc` will not work if `b` is really a property of some record or object.

The free pascal compiler (fpc) does allow this syntax in non-delphi mode, but both Turbo Pascal and Delphi never did.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such syntax in Delphi or Pascal. You can use `Inc`, though:

```
Inc(b, c);
```

Oxygene, the Delphi-like .Net product by RemObjects, allows the `+=` syntax for subscribing to event handlers, but that's not related to anything you'd be doing here.

Answer (score 0):

pascal doesn't have syntax like that, if you want to create addition operation, you just can using
**b:=b+c;**
or
**inc(b,c);**

you can use this syntax in c/c++

Answer (score 0):

You have inc(b,c) that replaces b:=b+c and dec(b,c) that replaces b:=b-c.

If you use these often I would recommend you to write your module and write these procedures for addition, subtraction, multiplication and division yourself. There may be a way to define your operators if you are willing, I'm not sure about this so i'd like if someone could clear this to me.

Comment: I checked and you only can't define your operators.